# Deployment of bundle without IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to host the app in the Windows service, so I don't use IIS. However almost [all the official examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-manifest.html) require IIS path. There is the only one which doesn't require it - "custom". I managed to run batch commands using that "custom" deployment but I don't understand how to copy the artifacts.

Comment: did you try these approach? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @Radik what do you mean? Like I said, I host the app inside the service. Everything works fine but I need to upload the artifacts to the end AWS machine, that's the thing. AWS config requires IIS but I don't use IIS

Comment: What kind of application do you want to deploy? If you are not shipping a typical web application, maybe you should check AWS Lambda.

Comment: It is a web site. Anyway, I cannot move from EB for now.

Comment: How do you host a web site inside a service?

Comment: @cassandrad as described in the official doc provided by Radik
It works based on Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices nuget with Kestrel web server

Comment: Then, you can't deploy your app in BE, because it can host only IIS-hosted apps (according to BE docs) which in your case isn't so. You have to change your hosting type to IIS instad of service if you want to host in BE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I understood how to solve it. If you needed something similar, you could use that "custom" deployment mentioned in the question, your bundle would be extracted to C:\staging and then copied to C:\staging-previous on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Just open a **command prompt** and navigate to the folder location where you have the code:

Publish an app self-contained. A **macOS 64-bit** executable is created.

```
dotnet publish -r osx-x64
```

Publish an app self-contained. A Windows 64-bit executable is created.

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64
```

Just past this published folder to the server and in CMD on the server just navigate to the folder in published folder on server than execute the following command **Must use your real project name in {Project-Name}**

```
dotnet run {Project-Name}.dll
```

this will execute your project on the server also you need to manage the webserver configuration for the DNS to behave like a webserver